# C# Facebook SDK - Problems getting Page Tabs - here's my code and error

Tags: sdk, tabs, facebook-c#-sdk

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("access_token", page.acces_token);
dynamic p = fb.Get(page.id + "/tabs", parameters);
```

Error:

```
(OAuthException) An access token is required to request this resource.
```

---

But I am providing an access token... What seems to be the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you copied and pasted that code, then the use of "acces_token" instead of "access_token" may be your issue.